# In memoir: section title in odd header, subsection title in even header

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I am currently using memoir for a longer document with only sections and subsections (and subsubsections and paragraphs). If I wanted chapter title and section title to appear alternately in the header, I could write

```
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{\rightmark}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{\leftmark}{}
```

But since I have no chapters in my document, I want to use section title and subsection title alternately instead. How do I do this?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\makepagestyle{plain}
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{\thesubsection want subsection title here}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{\rightmark}{}
\makeheadrule{plain}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

\usepackage[usehighlevels]{alnumsec}
\alnumsectionlevels{1}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}
\alnumsecstyle{aaaa}
\surroundarabic[{.}][]{}{}
\otherseparators{1}
\alnumsecstyle{aaaa}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\section{This appears in the header properly}
\subsection{How to get this into the header?}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Big thanks in advance!

Comment: This article might be useful http://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-2/madsen/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a question of those `\mark`* commands.  I think this is what you're hoping for (MWE exanded slightly):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}

\makepagestyle{plain}
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{\rightmark}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{\leftmark}{}
\makeheadrule{plain}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markboth%
  {\thesection.\ \MakeTextUppercase{#1}}%
  {\thesection.\ \MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection.\ #1}}

\usepackage[usehighlevels]{alnumsec}
\alnumsectionlevels{1}{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}
\alnumsecstyle{aaaa}
\surroundarabic[{.}][]{}{}
\otherseparators{1}
\alnumsecstyle{aaaa}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents

\section{This appears in the header properly}
\subsection{How to get this into the header?}
\lipsum[1-20]

\section{This appears in the header properly --- TOO}
\lipsum[1-20]
\subsection{How to get this into the header? --- TOO}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Basically, you want to "markboth" for `\sections` so that if there's no subsection, the information from the `\section` is used, but you want to "markright" with the `\subsection` information so it is used when available. I gather also that you want to keep the `\section` information in uppercase in the header.